# Is possible to update the sound of current notification?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have a helper class that helps me with building and showing one notification with 2 states.

In constructor I'm initializing `NotificationCompat.Builder` with common settings for both states. Then in one method (`showNotificationCircle()`) I'm showing notification with circle icon, some texts and a 'click' sound.

In another method (`showNotificationRect()`), I'm showing notification with another icon, some texts and another sound but when notification appears it is still the same sound no matter what method is used.

This is my constructor:

```
public NotifHelper(Context context) {
      clickSoundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.click_sound);
      bulbSoundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.bulb_sound);
      builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
      builder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.some_text_1))
               .setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white))
               .setAutoCancel(false)
               .setShowWhen(false)
               .setOngoing(true)
               .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS);
}
```

This is my method for circle state:

```
public void showNotificationCircle() {
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_circle);
        builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
        builder.setSound(clickSoundUri);
        notification = builder.build();
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}
```

And the second method:

```
 public void showNotificationRect() {
    builder.setContentIntent(pendinIntent2);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_rect);
    builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MIN);
    builder.setSound(bulbSoundUri);
    notification = builder.build();
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
 }
```

I have no idea why played is only 'clickSoundUri' instead of 'bulbSoundUri' when invoked is `showNotificationRect()`.

Comment: Could you show us the code where you initialize clickSoundUri and bulbSoundUri?

Comment: @gedo it is in constructor like that now.

Comment: @unibax99 do you have "instant run" enabled? Try disabling it. Then also try doing `Log.d()" thing in both the methods. If both ways fail, maybe cleaning the project will fix it.

Comment: @Sufian i did it, nothing changes...

Comment: @unibax99 what happens if you set sounds to "bulbSoundUri"?